# Play framework console not using custom config

Tags: java, playframework

I'm trying to use a custom configuration file to run the tests, but the following command is not working (it still uses application.conf):

```
play -Dconfig.file=/fullpath/conf/dev.conf test
```

Is there any alternative solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the `play id` to set an id for your play instance. Based on this, you can access environment specific settings in your `application.conf`.

For instance:

```
%dev.application.mode=dev
%prod.application.mode=prod

%dev.application.log=DEBUG
%prod.application.log=WARN
```